VBA Excel macro - error 5, fails before loop
I'm having trouble with this code.  Code loops through a directory of watershed data.  On single rate zone watersheds the suffix is _0, on multiple rate watersheds the files are split into subsheds _1, _2, _3, etc. to set the rate different codes.
The multi-sheds need merged back into a single _0 file to then be imported into tax software. All data is on sheet 1 of each workbook.  here's the code. It's hanging on on filename = Dir right before the loop.
I'm not seeing why it's hanging on the filename before loop - as I have other macros doing rate code changes, etc all using the same format - and they work.
Sub Merge()

Dim folder As String 'used
Dim path As String 'used

Dim fileName As String

Dim file() As String
Dim Watershed As String
Dim Subshed As Integer
Dim previous As Integer

Dim outputFileName As String
Dim wbOutput As Workbook
Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wbTemp As Workbook
Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
Dim fileCount As Integer

folder = Year(Now()) & "_Excel\"
'path = "J:\Projects\DekalbCo\Surveyor\Surveyor GIS Data\" & folder
path = "J:\Projects\DekalbCo\Surveyor\Surveyor GIS Data\2024_excel\test\"

' Loop through each file in the folder
fileName = Dir(path & "*.xls")
Debug.Print fileName

'initialize subshed to 0
previous = 0

Do While fileName <> ""

 ' Extract Watershed and Subshed from the filename
    file = Split(fileName, "_")
    Watershed = file(0) & "_" & file(1)
    Debug.Print Watershed
    Subshed = Left(file(2), 1)
    Debug.Print Subshed

    ' Check if Subshed is greater than 0
    If Subshed > previous Then
        previous = Subshed
        
        ' Check if output workbook exists for this prefix, create if not
        outputFileName = path & Watershed & "_0.xls"
        If Dir(outputFileName) = "" Then
           Set wbOutput = Workbooks.Add
           wbOutput.SaveAs outputFileName
           Set wsOutput = wbOutput.Sheets(1)
           isFirstFile = True
        Else
           Set wbOutput = Workbooks.Open(outputFileName)
           Set wsOutput = wbOutput.Sheets(1)
           isFirstFile = False
        End If
        
        ' Open the current file
        Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(path & fileName)
        Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Sheets(1)
            
        ' Copy data to the output workbook
        If Not isFirstFile Then
        ' Remove header from the second and subsequent sheets
            If wsTemp.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            wsTemp.Rows(1).Delete
            End If
        End If
        wsTemp.UsedRange.Copy wsOutput.Cells(wsOutput.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1)
            
        ' Close the temporary workbook without saving
        wbTemp.Close False
            
        ' Close and save the output workbook
        wbOutput.Close True
            
        ' Increment file count
        'fileCount = fileCount + 1
        
    End If
    
    ' Get the next file
    fileName = Dir
Loop
End Sub



Check the files in that directory are accessible, i.e. they are readable for your application.

Note that you are destroying your Dir-loop with the statement If Dir(outputFileName).... The statement fileName = Dir will never return another file.

I think there should be a parenthesis after the Dir  call in the "filename=Dir" statement

@FunThomas Do you have a suggestion as to how to fix it then?  I need to see if the _0 file for the subsheds exist - if not, I need to create it, then append the subshed files to that _0 file.  so here's a list of the file sample:  Final_3000_0.xls
Final_38200_1.xls
Final_38200_2.xls
Final_38200_3.xls
Final_39022_1.xls
Final_39022_2.xls
Final_39022_3.xls
Final_39022_4.xls
Final_38200_1-3 will get merged into Final_38200_0.xls
then the 39022_1-4 files will merge into Final_39022_0.xls  and so on.  There are files like Finaly_3000_0.xls that would get skipped. due to _0

@flaberenne: No, that's not necessary.

First collect all of the xls file names into (eg) a Collection, then loop over the collection.

@TimWilliams - i thought of that - but not sure how.  essentially I have a ton of small collections.  I need to iterate the directory, and find all of the filename prefixes (filename_xxxx) that are the same, then merge them or append them to a new file in order of the suffix (Final_newfile#_0.xls)  starting with final_xxx_1, final_xxx_2, final_xxx_3...etc.  then onto the next "group" of multiple suffix files.

Is the order of the collected subsheds in the "_0" file important?  What is the max possible value for subshed?

@TimWilliams, I would say the max subshed would be 9 - though I have only seen up to about 5 or 6.  this only applied to watersheds where the maintenance tax rate is split into multiple rate zones.  otherwise - the "0" files are a single rate - for Ag, RES, and COMM type properties.

Here's one suggestion for how to manage this (untested):
Option Explicit

Const PATH_ROOT As String = "J:\Projects\DekalbCo\Surveyor\Surveyor GIS Data\2024_excel\test\"

Sub Merge()
    Dim dict As Object, f As String, lr As Long, rngCopy As Range, k
    Dim Watershed As String, Subshed As Long, wbZero As Workbook, wsZero As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = 1 'case-insensitive
    
    'start by collecting all source files with specific pattern
    f = Dir(PATH_ROOT & "*_*_*.xls")
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        If InStr(f, "_0.xls") = 0 Then 'not collecting "zero" files
            dict.Add f, True 'a file we need to process?
        End If
        f = Dir()
    Loop
    
    'loop over files
    For Each k In dict
        Watershed = GetWatershed(k)
        Subshed = GetSubshed(k)
        'open source
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(PATH_ROOT & k)
        Set rngCopy = wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
        'open destination and copy content
        Set wbZero = ZeroFile(Watershed)
        With wbZero.Worksheets(1)
            lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If lr = 1 Then
                rngCopy.Copy .Cells(lr, 1)  'first data: include headers
            Else
                rngCopy.Offset(1).Copy .Cells(lr + 1, 1) 'skip headers
            End If
        End With
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        wbZero.Close savechanges:=True
    Next k
    
End Sub

'handle parameter extraction
Function GetWatershed(fName) As String
    Dim arr
    arr = Split(fName, "_")
    GetWatershed = arr(0) & "_" & arr(1)
End Function
Function GetSubshed(fName) As Long
    Dim arr
    arr = Split(fName, "_")
    GetSubshed = CLng(Replace(arr(2), ".xls", ""))
End Function
'construct file name
Function FileName(Watershed As String, Subshed As Long) As String
    FileName = Watershed & "_" & Subshed & ".xls"
End Function

'return a reference to the (opened) "zero" file for a given watershed
Function ZeroFile(Watershed As String) As Workbook
    Dim fName As String
    fName = FileName(Watershed, 0)
    If Len(Dir(PATH_ROOT & fName, vbNormal)) = 0 Then
        Set ZeroFile = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) 'has one worksheet
        ZeroFile.SaveAs PATH_ROOT & fName
    Else
        Set ZeroFile = Workbooks.Open(PATH_ROOT & fName)
    End If
End Function

Open question of whether the copy/paste order is important in each summary file.

order isn't necessarily important - as long as it's all of the subsheds of one filename, then a new file with the next subsheds files. , etc.

I just created a test with your code sample and ran it - it worked!  Thank you so much.  It's going to take me a bit to digest.  I understand what it's doing, but the method or sequence, I would have never thought of, as I am not that familiar with excel libraries and what's available functionally. I appreciate the help - this will speed up my process.  for our county, we have roughly 500 watersheds give or take, and collect at least 200 per year.  of those - I'd guess 30% require merging.  and before it was done manually.  I'm automating.  marked complete- thanks again!

Good to hear it's working out.

Tim, I have a couple questions.  The option explicit - and the Path root statement.  I'm calling this from a main macro - where I call several sub macros.  rename columns, filter and delete rows where benefit acres is less than 0.02, then reposition columns for imports, and change rates - then, merge if necessary.  I'm assuming the way you have it is a global variable?  but not sure I follow.

PATH_ROOT is a global variable visible to all code in the same module  - if you need that to be visible to code in other modules then update to Public Const Const PATH_ROOT As String = "path here" Option Explicit just means you can't refer to any variables you haven't declared or which aren't declared by VBA (such as eg. xlUp etc) - it's good practice to always include that at the top of every module.

once again, thanks Tim -
